# Failed to build LibcOverlayShims.h

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I am attempting to build a framework that I just ported some code from Objective C to Swift in, and I'm getting this error:

```
<module-includes>:1:9: note: in file included from <module-includes>:1:
#import "LibcOverlayShims.h"
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/usr/lib/swift/shims/LibcOverlayShims.h:80:15: error: declaration of 'sem_t' must be imported from module 'Darwin.sys.semaphore' before it is required
static inline sem_t *_stdlib_sem_open2(const char *name, int oflag) {
              ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/usr/include/sys/semaphore.h:43:13: note: declaration here is not visible
typedef int sem_t;
            ^
<unknown>:0: error: could not build Objective-C module 'SwiftOverlayShims'
```

The error is happening because of this one file:

https://github.com/losnoco/Cog/blob/swiftingly/Audio/Visualization/VisualizationController.swift

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you control `LibcOverlayShims.h`? If so, try adding `#include <sys/semaphore.h>` there.

Comment: `LibcOverlayShims.h` is part of Xcode, and included automatically by the compiler which is trying to produce the Objective C shims for the Swift code in the current project.